# MongoDB $near geospatial query with sparse compound index error 13311

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I've created a query to support address prediction, similar to Google Places autocomplete, where an input field will attempt to predict the address being entered by finding the nearest matching address (based on geo-ip-location) in the collection.

Each document in my collection includes an address string, and the coordinates of the address however not every document will have the address or coordinates.

The collection also includes a compound index created as follows:

db.collection.ensureIndex({ address: 1, coordinates: "2dsphere" }, { sparse: true, background: true });

My problem is when I perform a query, if the result set includes a document that has the address field but does not have the coordinates field, I get the following error:

{ $err: "wrong type for field () 10 != 2", "code": 13111 }

10 is the BSON type for null, 2 is the BSON type for string.

MongoDB's geospatial search is not skipping documents that do not have coordinates when there is a compound index. (It skips them fine using a simple index.) I tried to get around this by creating a sparse index, but the sparse option only applies to the first field in a compound index.

Is there a alternate way of performing a fast geospatial $near query and/or create a compound index that only includes documents where all of the index fields are present?

Comment: Add some coordination that not exists  eq 0,000000 0,00000000 and in query do $or

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MongoDB 2.4, `2dsphere` indexes are not sparse and do not recognise the `sparse:true` index modifier. All documents in a `2dsphere` geo index must have the geo fields present. By comparison, the older `2d` indexes *are* sparse by default (but do not support GeoJSON types).

This sparseness behaviour is changing in MongoDB 2.6.0-rc0 with the introduction of "V2" (version 2) `2dsphere` indexes. If you upgrade from MongoDB 2.4, existing `2dsphere` indexes will continue to have the current "V1" behaviour until you drop & recreate those indexes. There will also be a warning logged if you try to apply the "sparse" flag to a `2dsphere` index.

In V2 `2dsphere` indexes, if a document lacks a 2dsphere-indexed field (or the field is null or an empty array) the document will be inserted but not added to the `2dsphere` index.

For more information see [SERVER-9639 (2dsphere indexes should be sparse on geo fields)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9639) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at Userpassword's response and tried what he recommended. While not ideal it did work.

Essentially I updated the records that were missing data with a BSON location point of:

```
loc: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [0, 0] }
```

Again, this wasn't ideal in my situation either. However, the data without locations is now being silently ignored and I'll return to it if this changes to clean it up.